# Unused argument error in EpiR

Tags: r, verbose

I'm getting an unused argument error in the following code:

```
epi.tests(dat4, verbose = TRUE) 

# Error in epi.tests(dat4, verbose = TRUE) : 
#   unused argument (verbose = TRUE)
```

What could be causing this and how could I fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at `?epiR::epi.tests`.

The Usage section indicates that the function should be used as:

```
epi.tests(dat, conf.level = 0.95)
```

There is no `verbose` argument to that function - it only accepts `dat` (to which you are passing `dat4`, and `conf.level` (whose default is `0.95`).

Try again with `epi.tests(dat4)`.

Comment: Okay, thank you that makes sense. I think it must have been previously been part of the function as I'm going through a tutorial where it was used. How would I go about extracting specific parts of the list - like sensitivity, specificity?

Comment: @LauraB: take a look at the object's structure with `str(epi.tests(dat4))`. For sensitivity, for example, you might try `x <- epi.tests(dat4); x$elements$sensitivity`.